# Why there is no enableIvy property present in Angular 14 new project?

Tags: angular, ivy

I have the below environment and trying to create a new application with Angular 14.

- Angular CLI: 14.2.3
- Node: 16.17.0
- Package Manager: npm 8.19.2

I don't see enableIvy option in tsconfig file or aot property in angular.json file. Do we need to add these manually to enable ivy or it will by default be compiling with ivy?
Below is the default properties what I got in tsconfig.json:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The old View Engine was removed in Angular 13. So you don't have a choice, Ivy is the only option. Therefore the option to enable it doesn't exist anymore.

Cf. the history of Ivy:

- Angular 9 made Ivy the default view engine (https://docs.angular.lat/guide/ivy)
- Angular 12 deprecated View Engine (https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49)
- Angular 13 removed View Engine (https://www.theregister.com/2021/11/04/angular_13_released_ivy_everywhere/)